How am i able to change constant class member?
I came up with the way to change members of constant class and i don't have an explanation for it.
I came up with this example of code:
#include <iostream>

class Cool_class
{
  public:
    int x       = 1;
    int &x_ref  = x;

    void cool_method() const
    {
        x_ref = 2;
    }
};

int main()
{
    const Cool_class k_cl;

    std::cout << "before: " << k_cl.x << "\n";

    k_cl.cool_method();

    std::cout << "after: " << k_cl.x << "\n";

    return 0;
}


I compiled it with every sanitizer option possible. I do not understand how or why it works.

Its because its a reference member (This also applies to pointers). You are not changing the member x_ref you are changing what x_ref is pointing (referring to) at so you are not effecting the state of the current object.  OK. Yes you are being tricky by making it refer to an object inside the same object but that is you being sneaky the compiler does not check what you are pointing at (that is not part of the requirements of the language). Note: If this objects is truly const (as in this case) you have created undefined behavior.

Did you set the error level and warnings to maximum?  The statement x_ref = 2; should generate an error because you told the compiler that the cool_method() does not modify any members.  This is an issue that can be caught at compile time.

@ThomasMatthews The value of x_ref is not change so this does not invalidate the const of the method call. So this is not an error the compiler can detect. Note: it is still udefined behavior as the underlying object is const.

@ThomasMatthews No, references are the same as pointers in this respect.

@PasserBy A reference declared inside a const object can refer to a non-const variable, just as a pointer declared inside a const object can point to a non-const variable. In this particular example, the reference is declared as referring to a non-const int, so the compiler happily allows assignments to the referred int via the reference, even inside a const method of the parent class. The compiler does not know or care that the int in question happens to be inside a const object, so the assignment is actually Undefined Behavior.  The compiler can't verify UB, by definition.

Try this w/ a real const object instead the original main: int main() { static const Cool_class k_cl; k_cl.cool_method(); }

@3CxEZiVlQ The array is not necessary. And that code exhibits the same UB result as the original code: https://onlinegdb.com/xA49vVw7D

To prevent x_ref being used to change x (whether in a const member function or not), declare it as const int &x_ref = x.

@RemyLebeau Did you ping the wrong person?
